# Using Velocity, how could I count the number of elements of a list containing a string without a loop?

Tags: count, velocity, string-matching

I would like to count the number of elements in Velocity lists of this kind...

```
[Gender:male, Withdrawal:20160331, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISTU01];TU01;Rubén
[Gender:female, Withdrawal:201604131334, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISE027];E027;Ghizlane
[Gender:female, Withdrawal:201607221242, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISC014];C014;Miriam
[Gender:female, Withdrawal:201607221242, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISC014];C014;Inés
[Gender:male, Withdrawal:201607221223, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISC012, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISE007];C012;Alejandro
[Gender:male, Withdrawal:201607221223, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISC012, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISE007];C012;Alejandro
[Gender:female, Withdrawal:201607221223, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISC012];C012;María Dolores
[Gender:female, Adscription:20140512, Withdrawal:201607221223, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISC012];C012;Carmen
[Gender:female, Withdrawal:20160316, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISC009];C009;Margarita
[Gender:male, Withdrawal:201607261248, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISE020];E020;José Luis
[Gender:female, Adscription:20140512, Withdrawal:201608312127, Formerly:XWiki.XWikiIDISC012];C012;María José
```

... containing a given string. Let's say. "Formerly:". I can iterate over the list and count them but is there any more straight forward way?

Here you have a "life" example and its code...

http://atriumkm.idisantiago.es/bin/XWQL/MatchingCountSample
http://atriumkm.idisantiago.es/bin/XWQL/MatchingCountSample?viewer=code

I would like to filter out Items 5th and 6th in the result, files ending with "Alejandro", as "Formerly:" appears twice!

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry! I'm afraid I've missread your nice How to Ask section. I'll do my best to improve the question. Thanks for your time and sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and straightforward answer is to use StringUtils...

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Thanks for your time!